# How to create custom config section in app.config

Tags: c#-4.0, app-config

I want to add the custom configsection in the app.config file as follows

```
<Companies>
  <Company  name="" code=""/>
  <Company  name="" code=""/>
</Companies>

<Employees>
  <Employee name="" Des="" addr="" sal=""/>
  <Employee name="" Des="" addr="" sal=""/>
</Employeess>

<Departments>
  <Department Id="" Projects=""/>
</Departments>

<Projects>
  <Project Path=""/>
</Projects>
```

In the Department section it is referring to Projects section.

Can anybody tell me way to do it? And how to access it in my code?

@Bhaskar: Please find the code for your comment.

```
 public class RegisterCompaniesConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public static RegisterCompaniesConfig GetConfig()
        {
            return (RegisterCompaniesConfig)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RegisterCompanies")?? new RegisterCompaniesConfig();
        } 
        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("Companies")]       
        public Companies Companies
        {
            get
            {
                object o = this["Companies"]; return o as Companies;
            }
        }
    } 

public class Companies : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public Company this[int index] 
        { get { return base.BaseGet(index) as Company; } 
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
                } 
                this.BaseAdd(index, value);
            } 
        } 

        protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() 
        { return new Company(); 
        } 

        protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
        { return ((Company)element).Name; }
    } 



public class Company : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]   
        public string Name { get { return this["name"] as string; } }

        [ConfigurationProperty("code", IsRequired = true)]        
        public string Code { get { return this["code"] as string; } }
    }
```

Comment: Consider putting these settings in a separate XML file instead of in the app.config.

Comment: @Sjoerd , what is acheived by putting them in separate config files ? The entries should all be in one file as they are related.

Comment: @Geeta , In your code above I see this - `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RegisterCompanies")` - where is the section `RegisterCompanies` declared in your config file ? I can see only `<section name="Companies"` based on what you posted earlier.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful! I've learned how to deal with custom config sections from those excellent articles.

Answer (score 0):

I base all my configuration management code on the classes I collected [here](http://dotnx.sourceforge.net/). This is an [example](http://dotnx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dotnx/trunk/example/Core/ConfigExample/), and here's some [documentation](http://dotnx.sourceforge.net/doc/html/namespaceDotNX_1_1Config.html). Note that this is code I personally refactored from a blog post that isn't available on-line any more.

Comment: i have gone through your code.But you hav defined your own class to handle the collection like ConfigElementCollectionBase.However i want to do it using configuration collection element.If you know can you tell me how to write the code for the above section using ConfigurationElementCollection.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I just tried one simple example which is mentioned in one website.whenever i do ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Companies") its returning null.Can anybody tell me what is the exact problem.

Comment: @Geeta , you need to show your config file for me to point out the exact problem.

Comment: Please find the config file content                                                              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Companies" type="CustomConfigSectionTester.RegisterCompaniesConfig,CustomConfigSectionTester"/>
    </configSections>
  <Companies>
    <Company name="Tata Motors" code="Tata"/>
    <Company name="Honda Motors" code="Honda"/>
  </Companies>
</configuration>

Comment: have you defined your handler type "CustomConfigSectionTester.RegisterCompaniesConfig,CustomConfigSectionTester" ? If this is not defined , the corresponding section may not be loaded.

Comment: yes i have added RegisterCompaniesConfig class which is derived from ConfigSection.I also implemented ConfigurationElementCollection and ConfigurationElement.

Comment: Are you sure its `ConfigSection` you derive from ? This seems to be incorrect if I remember correctly - it should be `ConfigurationSection` I suppose. Without the code it will be difficult to guess but its obvious that your ConfigurationManager is unable to locate a scetion by name "Companies".